# How to use a MariaDB prepared statement query in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I've been searching for a method to make this MariaDB prepared statement to be able to run in node.js. The problem here is that the search term "MariaDB prepared statement in node.js" does not return results that I am looking for.

To clarify much further, I have a MariaDB prepared statement like below and I've been using it for most of my customized reports that my employer requested:

```
SET @columns := NULL;
SET @sql := NULL;
SET @df := '2022-01-07';
SET @dt := CURDATE();
SET @pc := 'barcode IN ("111", "222", "333")';

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN seq=1 THEN
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN barcode="',barcode,'" then sold_qty else 0 END) AS "',
        product_name,' \r\n ---- \r\n Sold Qty"')
              WHEN seq=2 THEN
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN barcode="',barcode,'" then sales_amt else 0 END) AS "',
        product_name,'  \r\n ---- \r\n Sales Amt"') END SEPARATOR ', \r\n' ) INTO @columns
FROM products
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 seq UNION SELECT 2) s
WHERE barcode IN ("111", "222", "333");

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT sales_date,
',@columns,' 
FROM (',
       GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT(
       '
       SELECT * FROM ',TABLE_NAME,' WHERE ',@pc) SEPARATOR ' \r\n UNION ALL \r\n'),
       ') v 
  WHERE sales_date >= "',@df,'"
  AND sales_date < "',@dt,'"
  GROUP BY sales_date;') into @sql
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'sales_tbl%'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(RIGHT(TABLE_NAME,6),'01'),'%Y%m%d') >= @df-INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Basically, I'm generating a pivot query and I'm creating the columns and defining the tables (for the `UNION ALL`) dynamically. My node.js (or even javascript) knowledge so far is still quite beginner-ish so I attempt to re-create this prepared statement query as-is and obviously failed. I do understand why it's not working though. I've tried multiple search terms to find any question in SO that is related to my issue but I couldn't find one.

The query does pretty well for me so I don't really have any issue with it. It's just that, I'm looking to develop a customizable web report app that everybody in my organization can use.

[Here's a fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d0ae9309d15a5dd755133e2fdb6539fa).

After further testing, I can actually use the prepared statement as-is in node.js but it requires me to add `multipleStatements: true` for the node.js [mysql client](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries); which I'm familiar with as I did use this method for my older projects however, it comes to my attention that using this setting is not exactly safe. I have an older question regarding this as well. Even though the web-app I'm building is just for internal usage, I (try to) prevent using unsafe practices.